# 7*4 mod(15) qiskit explanation

Tags: qiskit, shors-algorithm, modular-exponentiation

I don't understand this circuit's output from Qiskit's doc : [image: 7*4%15].
Indeed, the result should be 13, but output, I think I don't have the right method to read the result. I should have $|1101\rangle$ but we can see $|1110\rangle$ instead. Maybe the right result is report on the classical register but I don't know how to read it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. Which backend do you use? A real QPU or simulator? How many shots is used?

Comment: What section of the Qiskit docs is this from?

Comment: Your circuit is getting precisely the result it's supposed to.  Why do you believe it calculates 7 * 4?

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answers. This circuit is extract from the IBM quantum composer’s IBM user guide in « Shor’s algorithm » chapters (https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/composer/docs/iqx/guide/shors-algorithm). At the end of the article, there is a lot of example of 7xmod15. I understand the input x but I don’t know how to read the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the gate you made, the input isn't 4
[image: |7x mod(15)>]
Note that my input. $$|x_1\rangle = |q_3 q_2 q_1 q_0\rangle $$ In the circuit you made, would be something like:
$$ |x_2\rangle = |q_0 q_1 q_2 q_3\rangle $$
In conclusion, when $ |x_1\rangle = |0100\rangle = |4\rangle$, your state must be:  $|x_2\rangle = |0010\rangle = |2\rangle $ for a equivalent output value.

So you can either change the input state to 2 or the second SWAP gate's positon